# Offline web app is not working on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, offline-caching, iphone-web-app

I have created an offline web app using local storage and manifest file. Its working fine online and offline when user open it in browser. but when user open it from add to home screen icon from iphone. it  is showing error in offline mode.

here is cache manifest code example

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Cache manifest version 0.1
# If you change the version number in this comment,
# the cache manifest is no longer byte-for-byte
# identical.

/scripts/home.js
/scripts/read.js


NETWORK:
*
```

But it is showing following errors when user open it from add to home screen icon in airplane mode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've fought with same issue some time ago. I got it working with this kind of combination:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Cache manifest version 0.1

CACHE:
/scripts/home.js
/scripts/read.js

FALLBACK:
. .

NETWORK:
*
```

Comment: do i need to add a fallback section ?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I just got it working after several attempts. Read: http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag to understand the frustration behind.

Comment: I have tried its not working. do you have any working example for same?.

Comment: Did you try by changing the manifest version (e.g from 0.1 --> 0.11).

Another possibility causing error could be referring to `/scripts` with `/` prefix. And remember to clear your cache / history from Safari's settings before proceeding.

Comment: i have done all these things and also i have tried by adding the complete url of files with domain name. But not working in case of add to home screen

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 11.3, you can use service workers to accomplish this. Learn more at https://serviceworke.rs